# What is the difference between sys.stdin.read() and sys.stdin.readline()

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdin, readline, sys

Specifically, I would like to know how to give input in the case of read(). I tried everywhere but couldn't find the differences anywhere.

Comment: Perhaps read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.read) for the difference? For providing input to stdin, you're going to need to be a bit more specific; you can redirect files, or just type stuff at the terminal (though you usually want to use `input` in that case, not raw `stdin`).

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> help(sys.stdin.read)
Help on built-in function read:

read(size=-1, /) method of _io.TextIOWrapper instance
    Read at most n characters from stream.
    
    Read from underlying buffer until we have n characters or we hit EOF.
    If n is negative or omitted, read until EOF.
(END)
```

So you need to send EOF when you are done (*nix: Ctrl-D, Windows: Ctrl-Z+Return):

```
>>> sys.stdin.read()
asd
123
'asd\n123\n'
```

The `readline` is obvious. It will read until newline or EOF. So you can just press Enter when you are done.

Answer (score 1):

`read()` recognizes each character and prints it.

But `readline()` recognizes the object line by line and prints it out.